# How to change an algorithm of JWT in Apigee?

Tags: apigee, envoyproxy

I'm following a example from

> https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/envoy-adapter/v2.0.x/example-hybrid#prerequisites

In this example RS256 algorithm is being used.

How can I change it to HS512?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I change it to HS512?

You cannot change the **alg** to HS512.

Certificates do not use HS512. Certificates use asymmetric hashing using a private key (sign) and public key (validate). HS512 is a symmetric algorithm using a single secret that is shared.